# If rank of $(m+1)\times n$ matrix is $m+1$, then some $(m+1)\times (m+1)$ submatrix has non-zero determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I can't understand this :

> If I have a $(m+1)\times n$ matrix and if its rank is $m+1$, then some $(m+1)\times (m+1)$ submatrix has non-zero determinant.

How is it so?... kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If the rank is $m+1$, then the matrix must have $m+1$ linearly independent columns.

Comment: but I don't understand this ...how is getting $m+1$ linearly independent columns related to existence of a $m+1\times m+1$ submatrix having non-zero determinant..Please help..

Comment: A submatrix is formed by deleting rows and columns of the original matrix.  In this case you'd delete columns so as to leave $m+1$ linearly independent columns.  If the columns of a square matrix (which is what you'd be left with) are linearly independent, then the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: is there some theorem for this :if a $m+1 \times m+1$ matrix has $m+1$ linearly independent columns then its determinant is 0...

Comment: Yes.  See for instance here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be maximal such there is a non zero $k$ sub-determinant. Just assume that the subdeterminant is in the upper left corner. Then we claim that the rank is $k$. It cannot be less than $k$ since the first $k$ rows are independent. If we take any other row and consider the first $k$ elements of this row, they will be a unique linear combination of the upper left hand $k\times k$ rows. The coefficients of this linear combination give in fact a linear dependence between the entire rows, not just the first $k$ terms, since the combination is unique for the first $k$ terms. 
This shows that all $k+1$ rows are dependent and so the rank is at most $k$.